# Threading with Twisted with Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, twisted

I am currently working on a Battleship game project (for learning purposes) that uses tkinter for the UI and, because I want this program to be able to run on two computers for multiplayer, twisted for data transfer. This is my first time using twisted however I have used tkinter many times.

I know both twisted and tkinter run in loops so it is normally not possible to have these running in the same thread. So I found out there's two ways to get around this: `tksupport` and running twisted's `reactor` in a separate thread.

However, I tried to import `tksupport` from `twisted.internet` but it said that it didn't exist. I checked my twisted folder in my site-packages to be sure and it is indeed not there, but even the twisted docs claim it is. I assuming that this is because I am running python 3.5 and `tksupport` hasn't been ported over yet, but If this is not the case, please let me know.

Also, as for the solution with threading, I discovered there's some controversy over putting twisted's reactor in it's own thread. *Is it ok to put the `reactor` in its own thread, and, if so, what precautions should I take?*

Thanks.

Comment: According to my memory, Battleship is a turn-based game for which it is okay to freeze one players screen while waiting for a message from the other.  If so, I would consider using sockets to avoid the complications of asynchronous messaging.

Comment: @TerryJanReedy Yes, but like I said, this is for learning purposes. Basically I'm *purposely* making it more complicated than necessary so I can learn how to use twisted. But I am also trying to implement an in-game chat using twisted. Basically I plan to have two listeners, one for the chat and one for the game data. While you are correct in thinking the game data one can work with simple synchronous sockets, the chat one needs to be asynchronous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took a look at the source code for [twisted.internet.tksupport](https://twistedmatrix.com/trac/browser/trunk/twisted/internet/tksupport.py) and it appears it has not been ported to support Python 3. The culprit is the line importing the tkinter modules:

```
import tkSimpleDialog, tkMessageBox
```

In Python 3 the equivalent would be:

```
from tkinter import simpledialog, messagebox
```

To get around this until Twisted supports Tkinter for Python 3, you should be able create your own *tksupport* module:

```
# tksupport.py
from tkinter import simpledialog, messagebox
from twisted.internet import task

_task = None

def install(widget, ms=10, reactor=None):
    """Install a Tkinter.Tk() object into the reactor."""
    installTkFunctions()
    global _task
    _task = task.LoopingCall(widget.update)
    _task.start(ms / 1000.0, False)

def uninstall():
    """Remove the root Tk widget from the reactor.

    Call this before destroy()ing the root widget.
    """
    global _task
    _task.stop()
    _task = None

def installTkFunctions():
    import twisted.python.util
    twisted.python.util.getPassword = getPassword

def getPassword(prompt = '', confirm = 0):
    while 1:
        try1 = simpledialog.askstring('Password Dialog', prompt, show='*')
        if not confirm:
            return try1
        try2 = simpledialog.askstring('Password Dialog', 'Confirm Password', show='*')
        if try1 == try2:
            return try1
        else:
            messagebox.showerror('Password Mismatch', 'Passwords did not match, starting over')

__all__ = ["install", "uninstall"]
```

And following a slightly modified version of Twisted's [Tkinter example](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/choosing-reactor.html#tkinter) you would do:

```
import tkinter as tk
from twisted.internet import reactor

import tksupport

root = tk.Tk()

# Install the Reactor support
tksupport.install(root)

# at this point build Tk app as usual using the root object,
# and start the program with "reactor.run()", and stop it
# with "reactor.stop()".
```

Comment: So this is the same implementation of twisted's `tksupport` only using tkinter 3.x compatible imports?

Comment: @RobertR Yes, exactly.

Answer (score 1):

I currently have twisted 17.9.0 and python 3.6.
In reference to the answer above,
tksupport for python 3 is now available with twisted, so no need to create your own tksupport module.