# Tkinter and Twisted - creating a deamonic reactor in Python#

Tags: python, tkinter, twisted

I am trying to use tkinter and twisted in python 3.
I have followed this answer, [Threading With Twisted and Tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35229352/threading-with-twisted-with-tkinter) and it allows me get it to run.

But the issue is that when the code crashes or it is closed by the user, reactor is not stopped. How can I set it so that reactor is a deamon to the tkinter program. So far I have tried to just have it shut down the reactor when I close the tkinter gui which is not the ideal behavior (as I want to have both shutdown under any circumstance of failure) but would be the first step if I could get it to work.

my code is below

```
from twisted.internet import reactor, protocol
import tkinter as tk
import tksupport
import GUI 
def on_closing():
    reactor.stop()
    tksupport.uninstall()
    root.destroy()


root = GUI.BruGUI()
tksupport.install(root)
root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", on_closing)
reactor.run()
```

the tksupport code is from the previous link.

Comment: What do you mean "crashes"? What do you mean "reactor is not stopped"?

Comment: so  if I try to close the program by stopping the gui then the gui will stop but the reactor will not stop. When I try to run the above program again I get the error ReactorNotRestartable

Comment: The above program does not restart a reactor.  What _extra_ stuff is in the program you are _really_ running?

Comment: The issue is that it does not stop the reactor when it shuts down the gui. This means that when I start the script again (after it has been stopped) it creates the error that the reactor is not restartable. which is why I want to be able to be able to  make the reactor shut down when the gui is shut down.

Comment: When you say "shuts down" I want to interpret this as "the process exits" but I guess this _isn't_ what happens.  However, I'm just guessing.  Can you please explain what's happening in sufficient detail for your readers to follow along?  Consider <http://sscce.org/>.  Regarding your reading of the exception, "reactor not restartable" does not mean "you tried to start the reactor when it was running".  It means "you tried to start the reactor twice in the same process".  Twisted reactors do not support this.

Answer (score 0):

One simple way would be to put it in try/except block, but that's usually only a workaround:

```
try:
    from twisted.internet import reactor, protocol
    import tkinter as tk
    import tksupport
    import GUI 
    def on_closing():
        reactor.stop()
        tksupport.uninstall()
        root.destroy()


    root = GUI.BruGUI()
    tksupport.install(root)
    root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", on_closing)
    reactor.run()

except:
    reactor.stop()
    tksupport.uninstall()
    root.destroy()
```